# Does Homebrew cask keep apps updated in "real-time"?

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

For instance, let's say that I install Spotify with Homebrew. If a Spotify update comes out, will it also be available with brew upgrade the same way and day as if I were using the app installed via the Spotify website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] will it also be available with brew upgrade the same way and day [...]

No, you will have to run in the command line:

```
brew upgrade
```

to upgrade and wait a few days that someone push an upgrade into https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask.